# Проблема со спрайтами в Unity

Tags: unity3d

в моем проекте есть панорама,[image: 1] при повороте налево она смещается вправо, на камере виден как бы поворот налево при настроенном разрешении все отображается хорошо.[image: 2]
Также присутствуют кнопки на панораме, их 2 и они должны быть наложены на радио и рубильник, я сделал привязку по rect transform.

[image: 3]

При другом разрешении часть панорамы слева прибавляется, чего не должно быть
[image: 4]

также съезжают кнопки, указанные выше

[image: 5]

как это можно исправить, или все это из-за панорамы? Как бы можно разбить панораму на 3 части, но тогда придется двигать сразу 3 объекта, что будет сложно из-за плавного смещения, или появятся разрезы между частями панорамы.

---

все панорамы идентичны.
[image: 6]

с aspect ratio fitter, все равно кнопки съезжаются
[image: 7]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Можно больше подробностей? Что значит сьехали? Как выглядит картинка в движке? По скрину не понятно что вообще происходит

Comment: @Alemkhan Utepkaliev,  я исправил статью, посмотрите

Answer (score 1):

Переведите в окне `Game` разрешение экрана с `Free Aspect` на любое другое разрешение, вариантов много, так Вы можете проверить соответствие того как будет выглядеть игра на разных форматах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем во всех своих `Canvas`, в компоненте `Canvas Scaler` я назначаю `UI Scale Mode` на `Scale with Screen Size`, в основу ставлю своё эталонное разрешение на котором в основном стоит окно `Game`, и `Screen Match Mode` устанавливаю на `Match Widht Or Height` с значением 0.5, чтобы сравнивалось по среднему значению.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И конечно в самом `Canvas`, `Render Mode` ставлю `Screen Space - Camera`, с ссылкой на основную камеру.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это решает абсолютное большинство проблем с отображением изображений на любом устройстве

На счёт кнопок, дело в том что ваши "панорамы" как изображение на разных разрешениях меняют своё положение на экране, в отличии от кнопок, для этого есть специальный компонент `Aspect Ratio Fitter` и один прекрасный [видео материал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0uUuA3x0gU), с детальным обзором данного компонента. Компонент помогает регулировать размер изображения.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!!

Comment: еще вопрос, все работает, но при разных разрешениях панораму больше видно, на разрешении 2400 х 1800 часть панорамы слева прибавляется, а этого не должно быть, и съезжаются кнопки

Comment: Я рад что смог помочь, давайте Вы отредактируйте вопрос, где есть проблемы, попробуем решить

Comment: жду вашей помощи))

Comment: Приложите скриншот ваших панорам в инспекторе, немного дополнил ответ

Comment: дополнил статью

Comment: Используйте Aspect Ratio Fitter только на панорамные изображения, чтобы они не меняли размеры, кнопки оставьте на своих местах